# Nginx static website with wordpress blog routing

Tags: nginx, php, web-server

I have a problem with nginx config and after spending hours of trying different solutions I still can't make it work.

I have a root folder `/var/www/x` where I have my static website placed, lets say it is only one file `hello.html`. In that root folder I also have a `/blog` folder in which I have installed Wordpress.

What I want to achieve is to have a way to first check in my root folder for existing html file and if not found go to wordpress. Url can't be different for wordpress or static website.

Example:
`x.com/hello` will return hello.html file found in root.
`x.com/test` will go to `/blog` folder and feed to Wordpress controllers.

My latest solution is this and can't really understand why it does not work:

```
server {

        root /var/www/x/;
        index index.html index.php;

        server_name x.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri /blog/$uri =404;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/x.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/x.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = x.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name x.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: you did not show the complete configuration

Comment: Does the WordPress blog work correctly?